# Right-click an link and open in new tab does not trigger window eventlistener "load"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I have come across an issue which I never saw before. When a user opens a page in new tab, then my functions do not fire and the page needs to be reloaded manually to see the contents. This does not happen if a user just loads the page directly.

I have a laravel app and for the frontend I use laravel's blade system, but I load most of the content with AJAX with help of jQuery/JS.

I do this like this:

In blade a have a barebones layout and when the page loads I load everything:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    init_introduction();
    init_content();
});
```

I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init_introduction();
    init_content();
});
```

I also tried moving the files out of the ready and load functions and simply having them at the beginning of my JS file:

```
init_introduction();
init_content();
```

Why is that happening? The issue hapens only of a user uses the browser function by right clicking a link and opening the page in new tab. I need to keep this feature.

Can someone explain whats going on and how to fix it?

EDIT:

It seems it happens only on localhost. I run my app with "php artisan serve", so maybe its not an issue at all.